# Python PySide Event Handling

Tags: python, user-interface, event-handling, pyqt, pyside

I don't quite understand event handling in PySide.
When I try something like:

```
exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
```

where exitAction is previously made QAction that will be used to exit program it works just fine. But how come when I make something like

```
newAction.triggered.connect(QMessageBox.information(self, 'New document', "New document is being created...", QMessageBox.Ok))
```

it doesn't work? It shows QMessageBox whenever I start program, not when I click that QAction on toolbar/menu bar. How would I go on to implement QMessageBox as a result of clicking on an QAction? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you connect a signal you must specify the slot to which it is connected without actually calling the slot. Note that in `exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)` there are no parentheses after *close*. If you would write `exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close())`, the `close` method would be executed when you connect the signal (at the program start-up). This what happens in your second example.

If there doesn't exist a slot yet that does exactly what you want, you will have to create it yourself (with the parameters that the signal expects). For example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication, QMessageBox

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button = QPushButton('Click me!')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)

    def btnClicked(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self, 'New document', 
            "New document is being created...", QMessageBox.Ok)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Note that Qt [Signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) and Qt [Events](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html) are not the same! (your title says events but your post is about signals). In general I would use signals and only use events if there is no signal for what you want to do.